# inserting audit logging entry for user login

Tags: grails, audit-trail, audit-logging

I am using the grails 1.3.7 with audit logging plugin. I want to capture user login event like "user:PSam logged in at .." in the logs and since plugin does not have `onLoad` event defined, I am adding it to the domain classes and populate my own audit table entry in this event.
So in grails user domain class I do as follows

```
def onLoad = { 
        try {
         Graaudit aInstance = new Graaudit();
         aInstance.eventType= "User Log in"
         aInstance.eventDescription = "User logged in"
         aInstance.user_id = username
         aInstance.save(flush:true);
          println "username="+username
          println aInstance;
        }
        catch (e){
            println(e.getMessage())
        }
    }
```

I am having two issues here... 
1) the username property defined in this domain class as an attribute is coming up as null
2) it throws an exception saying: `No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here`

Is there another approach to be taken here? 
and also can use the plugins audi_log table to populated my onLoad() events entries?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Wrap yoyr logic in transaction:

```
def onLoad = { 
   Graaudit.withTransaction {
      try {
       Graaudit aInstance = new Graaudit();
       aInstance.eventType= "User Log in"
       aInstance.eventDescription = "User logged in"
       aInstance.user_id = username
       aInstance.save();
        println "username="+username
        println aInstance;
      }
      catch (e){
        println(e.getMessage())
      }
    }
}
```